# Opening Exec from different directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, terminal

Beginner linux user here,

I want to create an sh file which will open firefox, file explorer and sublime text, rather than execute these commands separately. I have created a bin folder in  /home/user and have saved my .sh file there. 
Everything runs as I want to except for running the sublime_text executable.
It cannot find the directory as I am running the sh file from the bin directory.

So, my question is, how can I open sublime text from another directory without creating another shell process to do so.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/user/
./Documemnts/sublime_text_3/sublime_text
xdg-open ~/Documents/sublime_text_3/sublime_text
firefox -new-tab -url https://www.google.com
xdg-open Documents/Work/
```

I get No such file or directory

or

error: error opening location: No application is registered as handling this file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the directory on line 2 is misspelled:

`./Documemnts/sublime_text_3/sublime_text`

Notice `Documemnts` vs. `Documents`

Comment: Didn't catch that, Thanks John.

Comment: Did that fix the script?